# Access the key value from an associative array

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap

I have the associative array `%cart_item`, within this is a series of associative arrays. I need to access the value of the keys within `%cart_item`. I have the following code which iterates on each array key. (I do the equivalent of php's continue if the value is 'meta')

```
my $key_value;
for (keys %cart_item) {
   next if (/^meta$/ || /^\s*$/);

}
```

I need to do something like this though (although this isn't valid), setting the value of the keys in the loop:

```
my $key_value;
for $i (keys %cart_item) {
   next if (/^meta$/ || /^\s*$/);
   $key_value = $i; 
   # do stuff             
}
```

Could anyone suggest a solution here? Apologies if this is obvious, I'm a Perl newbie. Thanks

Comment: Note on terminology: in Perl, associative arrays are usually called hashes.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks, is it worth updating the title?

Comment: I think it's fine as is. It might help people who aren't familiar with Perl's terminology find the question.

Comment: Regarding *associative arrays* —it's a dreadful name for a data structure. Ordinary integer-indexed arrays are "associative"—they associate an integer with a value. Python uses *dictionary*, while Ruby and Perl use *hash*; both are acceptable. In JavaScript, PHP and Lua, aggregate data behaves like both an array and a dictionary. They are called *arrays*, and they all have internal DWIM software that decides how to store each value. *Symbol table* and *hash map* are also acceptable, but as far as I know no language officially calls them *associative arrays*

Comment: They were called "associative arrays" until Perl 5 was released. When I see Perl programmers using the phrase I worry that they have learned Perl from horribly outdated sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking for

```
for my $key (keys %cart_item) {
   next if $key =~ /^meta$/ || $key =~ /^\s*$/;

   my $val = $cart_item{$key};
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for the value that goes with the key, you can get both at the same time with `each`:

```
while (my ($key, $val) = each %cart_item) {
  next if $key eq 'meta' || $key =~ /^\s*$/;
  ...
}
```

That's the equivalent of PHP's `foreach ($cart_item as $key => $val)`.

I also changed the "meta" check to use simple string equality; no need to use a regular expression for an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code has

```
for ( keys %cart_item ) {
   next if (/^meta$/ || /^\s*$/);
}
```

which works fine because the `for` has no loop control variable so it defaults to Perl's "pronoun" *it* variable `$_`. In addition, your regex pattern matches have no object so they also default to `$_`

Written fully, this would be

```
for $_ ( keys %cart_item ) {
   next if ( $_ =~ /^meta$/ || $+ =~ /^\s*$/);
}
```

but we don't have to write all of that. Some people hate it; others like me think it's absolute genius

Your non-working code

```
my $key_value;

for $i (keys %cart_item) {
   next if (/^meta$/ || /^\s*$/);
   $key_value = $i; 
   # do stuff             
}
```

*does* use a loop control control variable `$i` (bad name for a hash key, by the way). That's all fine except that your regex matches still

```
my $key_value;

for $i (keys %cart_item) {
   next if $i =~ /^meta$/ or $i =~ /^\s*$/;
   $key_value = $i; 
   # do stuff             
}
```

or, better still, stick with `$_` and write this

```
for ( keys %cart_item ) {
   next if /^meta$/ or /^\s*$/;
   my $key_value = $_; 

   # do stuff             
}
```